# CASE statement in WHERE clause : Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, data-warehouse

Below pasted is a sample SQL code which uses a case statement in where clause,but its throwing a syntax error saying "Expecting a Keyword like END between mrktng_pckge_typ_cd and NOT keyword.

`CASE WHEN  exc_ind=1 THEN 
mrktng_pckge_typ_cd NOT IN ('a','b','c','d') ELSE NULL END`

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve,  but I think in your then block you should set a value.  Your statement does not set any values.

Answer (score 6):

```
where      exc_ind <> 1 
        or mrktng_pckge_typ_cd NOT IN ('a','b','c','d')
```

In case exc_ind can be NULL -

```
where      coalesce (exc_ind,-1) <> 1 
        or mrktng_pckge_typ_cd NOT IN ('a','b','c','d')
```

---

For demonstration purposes:

```
where case when coalesce (exc_ind,-1) <> 1 or mrktng_pckge_typ_cd NOT IN ('a','b','c','d') then 1 else 0 end = 1
```

Comment: I need the 1st one . The scenario is like this ,if indicator equals to one i should not fetch the values mentioned for type code ,if indicator not equals to one i need all the data.This check should happen in the where clause .

Comment: To expand on the excellent answer, you can't combine `case` and `where in`.  You'd have to use dynamic sql for that, which macros don't support,  I don't think.  So you have to use this `or` logic.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to do like this. I have given different Table Name but you can do like this logic:

```
Declare @condition as int = 1
SELECT *
FROM mstCity
WHERE( (1=@condition and Name IN (SELECT AliasCity.Name From mstCity AliasCity WHERE AliasCity.Name NOT IN ('USA','UK') )) OR 
       (2=@condition AND Name IN (SELECT AliasCity.Name From mstCity AliasCity  ))
     )
```

Updated answer as per your query should  be like below:

```
WHERE ( ( exc_ind= 1 AND mrktng_pckge_typ_cd NOT IN ('a','b','c','d')) OR 
    ( exc_ind <> 1 AND 1=1 )
  )
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Snehal but this codes goes into a SQL MACRO ,so i cant use this variable logic there . Any other solution ?

Comment: you no need to use variable logic its just example. in your case you have to use  exc_ind=1 in first condition and in second condition you have to write exc_ind<>1

Comment: Down-voted (1) answering Teradata question with SQL Server code (2) Giving totally unrelated code as a reference (3) "AND 1=1". seriously?

Comment: Thanks snehal for your reply.